# Setting div to automatically fit it's content using display: inline-block - unexpected space

Tags: html, css

I'm using `display: inline-block` to make a `div` automatically expand to fit it's content. However, there seems to be an unexpected green space in the `div` *(with an arrow pointing to it)*:

[image]

To rectify this, I attempted to add `margin: 0;` to the `li` elements, however the issue still occurs.

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
}
li {
 width:100px;
 float: left;
 background: red;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: green; display: inline-block;">
<ul>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8xz0sze6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `<ul>` tag has padding from left and here you have defined green background to outer div thats why its showing space because there is default padding in `<ul>`

Add `padding:0px` in `<ul>`

```
ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

List elements uses padding to increase indentation so use `padding: 0`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: green; display: inline-block;">
  <ul>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<ul>` take padding on left side by default reset it and every thing will be fine

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
 width:100px;
 float: left;
 background: red;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: green; display: inline-block;">
<ul>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
</ul>
</div>
```